# Prevent ngb-accordion dragging, but still allow text highlighting

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

Prevent Accordion dragging, but still allow text highlighting

I have some data in a ngb-accordion where clicking it will expand and show the data. In side the accordion title, we have input box, When try to copy the input box content using mouse down, it is automatically adding the browser url to input box.  Since input box is added inside the accordion title, internally accordion title is using  links, the default behavior in HTML is to drag the link... but I want to disable that on certain links.

**TL;DR**: I want to be able to highlight the text of input which is inside the accordion title **and** not drag it.

Here is sample picture: when try to select the input box content, it copies the browser URL to input box value.
[image]

Here is my angular HTML code:

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
  <ngb-panel>
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
      <input class="no-drag" type="text" placeholder="sample" (click)="onclick($event);">
      Expand
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Panel 1
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel>
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
      <span>&#9733; <b>Fancy</b> title &#9733;</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Panel 2
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

The sample code is available here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kakf4g

1. We should be able to select the text in the input field by using mouse
2. It should not copy the browser url to input box.
3. It should work for the all major browsers like Chorme, Edge and Firefox.

**To fix the issues,**

I tried to disable the link dragging so issue 1& 2 is fixed with below css. It solves the issue for Chrome browser only, it doesn't solve the issue for other browsers.

```
:host /deep/ a {
    -webkit-user-drag: none !important;
}
```

Note: I added draggable='false' to the input box, but it didn't work. And angular is placing my input box in  tag so automatically my input box is getting link nature.
Any help will be appreciated.